# I want to Add Feedburner Right After Meta Details

Tags: wordpress

I want to add the Feedburner icon right after the meta details in all single posts. How can I do this? I am using the GeneratePress theme. Please help.

here is the Example: https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/effect-of-optimising-multiple-pages-for-the-same-keyword-phrases/

He Places the Feedburner icon right after the author-name in every single post.

The page I need help with: https://techlivo.com/

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Comment: @numanrki I can help you probably. Do you have a child theme in place already?

Comment: You can use 'generate_post_author_output' filter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.